# Comparing text in multiple cells using vba

Tags: vba, excel

lets say i want to compare these five of these cells together (where "line" is an integer) and if all of them have these exact words "Not Applicable" in them, i want the cell in output to also be "Not Applicable" I've tried replacing .Text with .Value but it doesn't work either. there's always a Run-time Error "13"

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim DocNo As Integer
Dim line As Integer

DocNo = (InputBox("Please input document number of record you would like to view"))
line = 1

'Checks the first cell of the results sheet until the number in first cell = the DocNo
'if "DocNo" = the number in the cell, Line is set to its respective y coordinate

Do
    line = line + 1
Loop While (DocNo <> Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 1))
If (Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 5).Text) And 
   (Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 57).Text) And 
   (Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 59).Text) And 
   (Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 32).Text) And 
   (Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 40).Text)  = "Not Applicable" Then
   Worksheets("Output").Cells(26, 3) = "Not Applicable"
End If

End Sub
```

If this is some stupid mistake please forgive me, I've only started using VBA for a few days

Comment: Voting to close this as the described error is due to a (few) typo(s), not about the algorithm itself. @Ledavidiado: If you run into more trouble with this, feel free to ask a new question or edit this one to reflect where exactly the trouble lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write it in a different way, unfortunately.

Say, you have texts in 5 cells, A1, B1, C1, D1 and E1 to simplify, you can either do

```
IF Range("A1").Value = "Not Applicable" And Range("B1").Value = "Not Applicable" ...
```

If I recall correctly, Excel has a native worksheet function doing the exact same thing - Exact( range, text )

Answer (score 0):

A little formatting goes a long way. Make sure to use appropriate code indentation, as shown below.

Here's the two main problems with your code:

- You had a line "the DocNo" that wasn't part of a comment, therefore wasn't valid code.
- You were messing an `End If` for your If block.

This code corrects these issues:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim DocNo As Integer, line As Integer

    DocNo = InputBox("Please input document number of record you would like to view")

    line = 1

    ' Checks the first cell of the results sheet until the number in first cell = the DocNo
    ' if "DocNo" = the number in the cell, Line is set to its respective y coordinate
     Do
        line = line + 1
    Loop While (DocNo <> Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 1))

    If (Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 5).Text) And _
        (Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 57).Text) And _
        (Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 59).Text) And _
        (Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 32).Text) And _
        (Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 40).Text)  = "Not Applicable" Then
        Worksheets("Output").Cells(26, 3) = "Not Applicable"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 If ((Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 5).Text)  = "Not Applicable") And 
 (Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 57).Text)   = "Not Applicable") And 
 (Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 59).Text)   = "Not Applicable") And 
 (Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 32).Text)   = "Not Applicable") And 
 (Worksheets("Results").Cells(line, 40).Text)  = "Not Applicable") Then
    Worksheets("Output").Cells(26, 3) = "Not Applicable"
End If
```